# Purple Ring stays on the right side on mobile, but goes back to left side on dekstop resolution

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

It would be awesome to make the ring always stay on the right side of the page! not just on mobile resolution.

I hope you guys will help me!

Dropbox with screenshots-  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wmyps4zg7tfardq/AABnsmXbAi5XZ29sCJdYA_uNa?dl=0

the theme for the webpage-  http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/

my code for the ring at this point:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                            <a href="#" >
            <img src="ring.png" style="; width: 2.5em; display:inline ; float:right;
                  padding-top: 14px ; height: auto !important"></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: create a fiddle not possible to tell anything by looking at the images need to see your html structure

Comment: Just updated- hope it helps

Comment: `float: right;` should work; what is the actual problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m61darfL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the image moves is that it is within the `.navbar-header` which changes size depending on break point.

**Can you move it out of the `.navbar-header`**

Can you place it in the element above `.container` this always has a full width according to your template.

**Can you have multiple buttons**

If your template comes with classes to hide and show across devices/screen sizes then you can have the button in 2 places for mobile and desktop.  Keep it where it is for mobile but hide when viewing on the desktop.  When on desktop you can add it the `.navbar-nav ul` li as a button but hide on mobile.

**Can you absolutely position it?**

```
<img src="ring.png" style=";height: auto !important; position:absolute;right:40px;top:14px;"></a>
```

You can change the `right` and `top` to position is correctly.

Depending on where you want it positioned on different screen sizes you might want to look at making the inline styles a CSS class and then using media queries to position for different resolutions.  For example a mobile first approach could be.

```
.header-ring{
    height: auto !important; 
    position:absolute;
    right:40px;
    top:14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .header-ring{
        right:100px;
    }
}
```

*Generally i'd try and not use inline styles.  Your template is responsive and as a result layout of your page will change across breakpoints - something that inline style tags are not good for.*

Comment: Could you please correct this fiddle, i have absolutely o idea whats the problem

Comment: That is a beast of a fiddle